# Continuity in weak formulation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, continuity

Good evening! Lately I often encounter terms like the following in some weak formulations of pdes:

$$\displaystyle\int_Ef(x,t)g(x,t)|^{\tau_2}_{\tau_1}\,dx$$

where $f,g\in L^2(E\times[t_1,\tau_2])$ are some $L^2$ functions on a space-time cylinder, with the extra assumption $f\in C([\tau_1,\tau_2])$. Why is the continuity often times needed? g btw is supposed to be some arbitrary test function (which isn't continuous). The continuity is not needed here in order to make sense of the pointwise evaluation of $f(\cdot,\tau_1)g(\cdot,\tau_1)$ and $f(\cdot,\tau_2)g(\cdot,\tau_2)$ or do I misunderstand something as we only have two a.e. functions? Also, why is continuity just assumed for $f$ but not for the arbitrary test function g? Or is the continuity often times assumed early as it's really useful later on (or even indispensable)?